# Dispatch Custom Events Using "this" or "window"?

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element, custom-events

When I create a web component (I'm using lit/lit-element in particular) that dispatches a custom event, I can:

Dispatch the event from `window`:

```
const evt = new CustomEvent("my-custom-event", {detail: "some-data"});
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Or dispatch the event from the web component itself (`this`):

```
const evt = new CustomEvent("my-custom-event", {detail: "some-data"});
this.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Is there a reason why I may want to do one versus the other?

Comment: `window` events are global and not related to a specific instance.

Comment: Events **bubble up the DOM**, so it all depends where in the DOM you want to listen

Comment: Learn: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-events/

Comment: If you want some parent elements to listen to the event and be able to distinguish between which of the custom elements have dispatched the event then you have to dispatch on the instance. if the event has a global nature to it then it doesn't matter. but if you want to e.g. dispatch the event after the element was removed from the DOM, then your only option is to dispatch on the window, assuming the event listener was not necessarily added to that element but to a parent.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use window as an event dispatcher to dispatch custom events, and to add handlers that handle them.

```js
window.addEventListener("xyz", event => console.log(event.detail));

event = new CustomEvent("xyz", {
  detail: {
    action: "didInitialize",
    payload: 3
  }
});

window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Output:

```js
{action: 'didInitialize', payload: 3}
```

The Event has `timeStamp` and all the usual event properties.